# Stopping a merge join with one input without data in SSIS

Tags: ssis, merge, output, inner-join

I would like to know if there is a way to stop the execution of a workflow involving a merge join (option: inner join) when one of the sources does not have any output. I mean, a case like this:

[image]

Useful in my case when I have to look for information from different sources and some days I can have zero registers from one of them according with some conditions, but the other one still continues validating the condition of the query and giving results (a considerable quantity sometimes).

Comment: No way I know of.   I would consider doing a pre-check and using a different dataflow task if one of the sources didn't have any data.

Comment: Agreed with @TabAlleman - Run an Execute SQL task to return the TOP 1 rows from the query that is used in Source 2, then skip the data flow if no data is returned. (could do the same for source 1 also)